# Shall you? Will you?

Tags: tag-questions

I often hear questions like *will you?* or *shall you?* used in an unusual way, and I would like to understand what that usage is for. Take this conversation for example:

- How were you able to do it?
- You shall never know, shall you?

This *shall you?* isn't a normal questions, he's not really asking the other party to if he *shall* or *shall not. But what does it mean?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: it's a **[tag question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-questions)**

Comment: I really don't believe that you "often hear" usages like *You shall never know, shall you?* from native speakers. It's "grammatical", but virtually no-one would use ***shall*** there - it's always ***will*** (in speech, usually contracted to ***'ll*** after an explicitly-stated subject).